# Add List of Generic Type to another

Tags: java, android, collections

```
private List<? extends BaseModelBO> overAllItems = new ArrayList<>();
```

**I am trying to add another list of same type to it.**

```
List<? extends BaseModelBO> newList = getResponseList(webServiceResponse.getResponse());

if (newList != null && newList.size() > 0)               
    overAllItems.addAll(newList);
```

Also tried `List<AnyClassWhichExtendsBaseModelBO>` to it..

like

```
List<ContactBO> contactList = getContacts(); //where ContactBO extends BaseModelBO

overAllItems.addAll(contactList);
```

*Error LOG*

```
addAll in List cannot be applied to java.util.List<capture<? extends BaseModelBO>>
```

**See error Image**

[image]

Comment: try this List<Model> overAllItems = new ArrayList<Model>(newList);

Comment: *I am trying to add another list of same type to it.* Not really. The wildcard `?` points to an unknown type, meaning `overAllItems` and `newList` might be restricted to different subclasses of `BaseModelBO`. There's rarely a good reason to assign a new collection to a wildcard variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is caused by the compiler doesn't know the correct type of `? extends BaseModelBO`, so when `addAll` the compiler will not know what's type should be applied in there, and throw this **compile error**. so you can do it like:

```
private List<BaseModelBO> overAllItems = new ArrayList<>();
```

Answer (score -1):

Change type of `newList` to:

```
List newList = getResponseList(webServiceResponse.getResponse());
```

Now compiler gives warning that List is a raw type, but no error.

Comment: This is terrible advice. The warning is there for a reason.

Comment: But this will work

Comment: If by "work" you mean "compile, and blow up when you're least expecting it".